# Django ImageField Alternatives

Tags: django, django-models, shared-hosting, imagefield

I am using shared host with virtualenv to run Django
Things run well, however, I can not use ImageField because gcc can not run, and I can not install Pillow.

Is there any other way that can be use instead of ImageField ? 
Can I use FileField instead ? As I know it has problem with image dimension or something.

Thank you

Comment: What do you need to do with the images? You can definitely use `FileField`...

Comment: I just want to display it , with a fixed size

Comment: You can definitely do that with a `FileField`.