# Can't use ImageField in Django now. Any alternatives?

Tags: django, imagefield, filefield

I have been working on a deep learning Django app that requires `PIL` installed. Now, I want to handle some images sent from an Android app. `Imagefield` seems to depend on `Pillow`. But both PIL and Pillow can't exist together.

Can `FileField` be used for this purpose? How do I approach now?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544126/django-imagefield-alternatives)?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference from `FileField` is that `ImageField` [adds extra validation and attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField). You should be fine using a [custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27081099/2915402) or the [model's clean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278753/clean-method-in-model-and-field-validation).